# SQL Query - Finding the Rank of a User in a Quiz

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a QuizAttempt table in my database as follows

```
| QAID | QID | UID | Score | Time |
| ---- | --- | --- | ----- | ---- |
|   1  |  5  |  3  |  119  |  105 |
|   2  |  5  |  3  |  117  |   70 |
|   3  |  5  |  3  |  119  |   90 |
|   4  |  5  |  4  |  120  |  130 |
```

where `QAID` = Quiz Attempt ID, `QID` = Quiz ID, `UID` = User ID, `Score` = Score in that attempt, and `Time` = Time taken in Secs

I want to get User Ranks based on Score first in descending & if Score is same then Time in ascending. Also I have to Group the Users who have taken the quiz more then one time and show their best attempt.

So the result should be like this (Grouped UID 3)

```
| QAID | QID | UID | Score | Time |
| ---- | --- | --- | ----- | ---- |
|   4  |  5  |  4  |  120  |  130 |
|   3  |  5  |  3  |  119  |   90 |
```

I know I can apply Group By UID and then Max(Score) but additionally I have to choose the Time also against that record, but do I pick up the min score next to 119 in a GROUP BY?

Because if i write

```
Select QID, UID, Max(Score) as Topper, Min(Time) as MinTime from QuizAttempt 
Group By QID, UID
Order By Topper DESC
```

I get this

```
| QID | UID | Topper | MinTime |
| --- | --- | ------ | ------- |
|  5  |  4  |  120   |   130   |
|  5  |  3  |  119   |   70    |
```

I get 70 which is overall Min(Time) and which belongs to record with **Score 117**

And If I try this

```
Select QID, UID, Max(Score) as Topper, Min(Time) as MinTime from QuizAttempt 
Group By QID, UID,Score
Order By Topper DESC
```

I get

```
| QID | UID | Topper | MinTime |
| --- | --- | ------ | ------- |
|  5  |  4  |  120   |  130    |
|  5  |  3  |  119   |  90     |
|  5  |  3  |  117   |  70     |
```

How should i correctly do the grouping? I am using **MS SQL Management Studio 2008**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select qa.*
from (select qa.*,
             row_number() over (partition by uid order by score desc, time asc) as seqnum
      from QuizAttempt qa
     ) qa
where seqnum = 1;
```